# Error with panel data (plm) Error in crossprod(t(X), beta)

Tags: r, plm

I have a df (a `pdata.frame` object):

```
head(df) :
        Company Year Kapitalinkomster Bank.o.kassa Obligationer      Lån       Aktier Placeringar.andra.ftg   Fodringar Reala.tillgångar
5-1948        5 1948         4.009780    0.8677505     40.12268 54.80897 1.4630271422           0.049855191 0.633959879     1.581139e+00
6-1948        6 1948         3.221688    0.9311173     71.16401 26.39038 0.4678139417           0.000000000 0.437931676     4.931845e-01
12-1948      12 1948         3.136025    0.7628832     46.10452 44.85120 4.1966304368           0.003740003 1.020092197     2.683785e+00
19-1948      19 1948         1.862666    0.1865510     16.82441 31.67412 0.7308074302          46.245334945 3.459693951     6.213455e-01
20-1948      20 1948         3.724516    1.7719721     70.98456 27.18631 0.0004305687           0.056565968 0.000165769     4.305687e-07
21-1948      21 1948        11.288744    1.1572048     64.21109 33.42962 0.2890377378           0.000000000 0.912175552     1.150518e-06
        Övriga.tillgångar
5-1948       0.4726258998
6-1948       0.1155685107
12-1948      0.3771504323
19-1948      0.2577362013
20-1948      0.0000000000
21-1948      0.0008697916
```

I then try to do a `random` model with `plm` package (Kapitalinkomster variable is regressed on the remaining variabler):

```
library(plm)
random <- plm(formula=Kapitalinkomster~ Bank.o.kassa+Obligationer+Lån+
  Aktier+Placeringar.andra.ftg+Fodringar+Reala.tillgångar+Övriga.tillgångar,data=df,index=c("Company","Year"), model="random")
```

I can get the output :

```
random

Model Formula: Kapitalinkomster ~ Bank.o.kassa + Obligationer + Obligationer + 
    Lån + Aktier + Placeringar.andra.ftg + Fodringar + Reala.tillgångar + 
    Övriga.tillgångar

Coefficients:
          (Intercept)          Bank.o.kassa          Obligationer                   Lån                Aktier Placeringar.andra.ftg 
            0.7204962             0.0441635             0.0297014             0.0618975             0.0023219             0.0142085 
            Fodringar      Reala.tillgångar 
            0.0341745            -0.0104192
```

Above I can see the  `Övriga.tillgångar` variable in `Model Formula` but not in `Coefficients`..

The problem is also that I cant get the `summary` when `Övriga.tillgångar` variable is included:

```
summary(random) :
Error in crossprod(t(X), beta) : non-conformable arguments
```

If I exclude it, the `summary(random)` works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you use `Obligationer` twice in the model formula?

Comment: Copy paste error. But I got an answer actually. I need to omit one variable from formula in plm.

Comment: You maybe know some nice way to save the summary(random) output? I use `textplot( capture.output(summary(random)), valign="top")`

Comment: You can save an R representation of the model fit with `save(random, file = "filename.RData")`.

Comment: Is the problem variable perfectly correlated with company or whatever your id variable is?

Comment: Hi, have you made any progress on that? I've encountered very similar problem and would like to see if this was solved.

Comment: @Konrad: this should be solved for `plm` >= 1.6-4 (Dec 2016)